# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mimetypes'

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

The following error pops out whenever I enter commands like
`conda info -e`
`conda update condo`
or
`conda create env -n 123` in the terminal.

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    from ..gateways.connection.download import download
  File "/Users/liguolun/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests import ConnectionError, HTTPError, Session
  File "/Users/liguolun/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import urllib3
  File "/Users/liguolun/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
  File "/Users/liguolun/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .request import RequestMethods
  File "/Users/liguolun/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/request.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .filepost import encode_multipart_formdata
  File "/Users/liguolun/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/filepost.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .fields import RequestField
  File "/Users/liguolun/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/fields.py", line 3, in <module>
    import mimetypes
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mimetypes'
```

How can it be fixed?

Comment: What's the other error?

Comment: Mostly Anaconda does not any module named `mimetypes`. Even in Anaconda Navigator, this module is not present!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the command in command-prompt: `pip install mimetypes` and reopen the file.
Hope it works!

Comment: According to https://github.com/davidteather/TikTokBot/issues/5 , it seems like ```mimetypes``` is a standard package in python so I got the following error: ```>>>ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mimetypes
>>>ERROR: No matching distribution found for mimetypes ``` Is there any other way?